# Passenger do not find mail gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, passenger

My app is working with no problems in my local machine, but when I upload it to my server, I get this error:

`Could not find mail-2.2.14 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)`

I checked with gem list and mail-2.2.14 is installed, I don't know what is happening. I uploaded another app to the same server and it worked fine.

Anyone can help me ?

**EDIT**

I Solved the problem running

```
bundle update mail
```

Answer (score 0):

Check which ruby your passenger is using.

- If you are using nginx, go to nginx.conf and check what is the value for passenger_ruby property
- If you are using apache, go to httpd.conf and check what is the value for PassengerRuby property

Make sure that is the same with the value with the ruby from `which ruby` command.

If you are using bundler, make sure you already run the `bundle update` command.

Comment: I'm in a shared host, so I can't access the httpd.conf file, but I don't think that's the problem. I deployed another app (that use ActionMailer, too) an it worked fine, but this one I can't get to work. Thanks for your quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking in the gem in your vendor/cache folder.

`bundle install` should cache the gems locally and install from them if they are present.

Do you have a full stack trace?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried bundle install with no success. But I solved the problem with bundle update mail :)